# Predicate to detect if Prolog Term was specified (became more specific)

Tags: prolog

Is it possible to get a predicate with already built-in ones (in swi-prolog) such that:

```
Wanted_Pred(X, a) %false
Wanted_Pred(b, a) %false
Wanted_Pred(X, Y) %true
Wanted_Pred(X, X) %true
Wanted_Pred(X, [Y|Z]) %false
Wanted_Pred([A|B], [X,Y|Z]) %false
Wanted_Pred([A,C|B], [X,Y|Z]) %true
```

e.g. succeeds iff both arguments represent each others free variable renaming,
note that copy_term doesn't do it as it unifies arguments in the end:

```
copy_term(X, a) %true 
copy_term(X, [Y|Z]) %true
copy_term([A|B], [X,Y|Z]) %true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[subsumes_term](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subsumes_term/2)/2 perfectly fits your requirements, just swap the arguments:

```
?- subsumes_term(a,X).
false.

?- subsumes_term(a,b).
false.

?- subsumes_term(Y,X).
true.

?- subsumes_term(X,X).
true.

?- subsumes_term([Y|Z],X).
false.

?- subsumes_term([X,Y|Z],[A|B]).
false.

?- subsumes_term([X,Y|Z],[A,C|B]).
true.
```

I've seen a fairly recent thread on SWI-Prolog mailing list on the efficient implementation of [(=@=)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=@=%29/2)/2, that I think it's related (actually, it also satisfies your requirements): putting it to good use should be the best option available.

**edit** correcting the link to mailing list. Recent switch of list' hosting to google groups made the archive unavailable...

You can find the thread for instance in [archived discussions](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.prolog.swi/14101/match=kuniaki+mukai+subsumes_term), searching for the author, Kuniaki Mukai

Comment: Thanks chac! That is exactly what I was searching!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the predicated I am searching implemented by me but
**I WANT TO FIND OUT IF THIS KIND OF PREDICATE IS BUILT_IN OR SIMILAR ONE IN SWI-PROLOG**.

```
true_copy(X, Y) :-
    (X == Y, !);
    (var(X), var(Y), !);
    ((var(X); var(Y)) -> !, fail);
    (atom(X), atom(Y) -> !, fail).

true_copy([X | L1], [Y | L2]) :-
    !,
    true_copy(X, Y),
    true_copy(L1, L2).

true_copy(Term1, Term2) :-
    Term1 =.. L1,
    Term2 =.. L2,
    true_copy(L1, L2).
```

Comment: `true_copy(f(X,X),f(_,_)).` succeeds. But is `f(X,X)` really a "true copy" of `f(_,_)`?